# Why constructor function prototype can be assigned to an object and what it means

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am reading through the official docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

and in the chapter `Different ways to create objects and the resulting prototype chain` -> `With a constructor` they have the following:

```
function Graph() {
  this.vertices = [];
  this.edges = [];
}

Graph.prototype = {
  addVertex: function(v) {
    this.vertices.push(v);
  }
};

var g = new Graph();
// g is an object with own properties 'vertices' and 'edges'.
// g.[[Prototype]] is the value of Graph.prototype when new Graph() is executed.
```

But right before that it is written that:

```
// Functions inherit from Function.prototype 
// (which has methods call, bind, etc.)
// f ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

So, `Graph` is a function and it should have `Graph.prototype`, in my understanding, to be of type `Function.prototype` and `NOT` `Object.prototype`, otherwise `Graph` would stop being a function and would instead become an object, or so I would think.

Could anyone explain why the `prototype` of `Graph` is assigned to an object and why the specified behavior of inheriting then `addVertex` becomes possible? Would we lose all of the function properties (`call`, `bind`) when such assignment happens?

Comment: `g` is an instance of `Graph`. `Graph` is an instance of `Function`. This does not mean that `g` is a `Function` instance as well (it's definitely not a function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two *different* prototype chains at play:

1. The prototype chain of the constructor
2. The prototype chain of objects that are *created* by that constructor

They have nothing to do with each other. The first is a function and thus related to `Function.prototype`, the other is not a function, but an object whose prototype object is created at the same time as the constructor function object was created. That prototype object will be used when a new instance is created by calling the constructor with `new`.

What can be confusing here, is that the constructor has a property that is called `prototype`, but that is *not* the prototype object of the constructor (point 1), but of objects it can create (point 2). Possibly this property would have been better named `prototypeForConstructedInstances`... but that's a bit long ;-)

To get the constructors own prototype you would write `Object.getPrototypeOf(constructor)`,... and you'll see it is `Function.prototype`.

You may have an interest in reading more about the broader subject of prototypes at ["How does JavaScript .prototype work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/5459839). It's an interesting read, and you'll also find [my answer over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880438/5459839).